# Cannot convert from 'typeA' to 'typeB' when attempting dynamic binding in C#

Tags: c#, overloading, dynamic-binding

I'm trying to design an API that is supposed to have a certain method for each of the 20+ concrete classes that I need to support (I can't change those specs).

My first idea was to use overloading to have the same method with different parameters and being able to automatically invoke the correct one based on the concrete class, however I'm getting the error in the title and I was wondering if there was a better way to do this (without having to use if/switch on object's type).

Here's a quick **pseudo-code** example:

```cs
class BaseClass {}
class ChildClassA : BaseClass {}
class ChildClassB : BaseClass {}

class Factory {

    public static void Build(ChildClassA obj){}
    public static void Build(ChildClassB obj){}

}

class Main {

    public static void Main(string[] args){
        BaseClass obj = getFromSomewhereRemote();
        Factory.Build(obj); // This is the line where I get the error
    }

}
```

I understand that I could build a method like this one:

```cs
void Build(BaseClass obj){

    switch (obj){
        case BaseClassA objA:
            Build(objA);
            break;
        ....
    }

}
```

but I was wondering if I could have the same results without switching on types.

Comment: `= new ChildClassA();` types the `var` as `ChildClassA`, and given that you have these overloads (`Build(ChildClassA obj)` etc) for each type, I don't see how you could be getting that error with this code.

Comment: There is no `Build()` method in class `Main`

Comment: 1. No `Build()` in `Main` 2. `Factory.Build` has private access.

Comment: What exactly does your `Build` method do? Is it the same for each class?

Comment: "the error", which error do you get exactly?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen "Cannot convert from 'typeA' to 'typeB'".

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]? The code in your question would simply state that there is no method on the Program type called Build, so that won't work. I want to see how you're attempting to call the method on the Factory type, because that's not what you're doing right now.

Comment: The code in your question produces the compiler error "CS0103 The name 'Build' does not exist in the current context", meaning that the code in your question is not the code you're actually using, that produces that error message. Please post actual code that produces that error message.

Comment: And if you make the two Build methods in Factory public, then change the code in main to be: `new Factory().Build(obj);` it will not produce that error. Again, please post code that actually produces this error message.

Comment: @Gserg: you're right, the example was a bad one. I edited it to make it clearer based on my requirements.

Comment: Why even with edit didn't you bother to provide correct code ? `Factory.Build` implies a static method which doesn't match what you provided inside the `Factory` class. In general I don't think it's enough to provide a pseudo code If you want an assistance with a compilation error.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov because I can't provide any code as I'm not its owner. Why would you need the exact code for something like that? Does adding `static` to both `Build` methods make the question easier to understand?

Comment: Because code you provided doesn't behave in way you stated, which most likely indicates that you omitted some details. A verifiable example will make the question easier to understand and the fact that your code isn't compilable per se, and minor changed to make it compilable don't make the problem reproducible, means that you code isn't verifiable.

Comment: _Because code you provided doesn't behave in way you stated, which most likely indicates that you omitted some details._ It's not true. Pasted [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VNM3Rj) after adding `public static` to `Build` methods, here you have the error on line 18. I think you're all focusing on the wrong thing in this question.

Comment: Ok, in the first edition there was explicit `ChildClassA` construction, now I see it's changed - I missed this piece.

Comment: I'm not sure what the `Build` methods are supposed to do but as they can be candidates to be a part of `BaseClass` as they are used in dynamic binding.

Comment: Each child class has a different logic for the `Build` method. EDIT: I can't change anything in those classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not recommended, but you can do something like this with `dynamic` keyword. Dynamic uses reflection under the hood so there is a performance issue. This will avoid lot of if statements. Runtime will decide which method will take.

```
 void Build(ChildClassA obj)
 {
     obj.MethodA();
 }

 void Build(ChildClassB obj)
 {
     obj.MethodB();
 }
```

And call:

```
Build((dynamic) baseClassObj);
```

Comment: I didn't think about using `dynamic`. If the performance hit is not that big, I might consider it instead of writing countless if statements.